# How to use pythons in operator in a dataframe to search for a string and return boolean in a new column in the same dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-science

I have a dataframe df which contains movies data.
[image].

I want to create a new column in df called "drama_movie" which contains the value True for the movies that are Dramas and False for if they are not.

I tried it with following code:
`df["drama_movie"]=df['listed_in'].isin(["Dramas"])`

-> but I receive everything as False in the column drama_movie.

When I try the following code:
`df["drama_movie"]=df.apply(lambda x: x['listed_in'] in x['Dramas'], axis=1)`

-> I receive a key error "Dramas"

What works is this code:
`df["drama_movie"] = df['listed_in'].str.contains('Dramas', case=False, na=False)`

-> But I need to use pythons in operator. I'm somehow stuck with it.
Any suggestions? Thank you for your help

Comment: "*I need to use pythons in operator*" -> why do you **need** this?

Comment: Do you mean that this is an assignment?

Comment: `df.apply(lambda x: 'Dramas' in x['listed_in'], axis=1)` should work, but this is a bad use of `apply`

Comment: kind of. I passed a test but the feedback was that I didn't use the appropriate code to solve one part and that I should look at it as it is relevant for understanding and future progress. But as you can see I couldn't figure it out. Your solution worked. thx. what was my problem? I was close with the solution, but something went wrong.

Comment: It's always hard to judge ratings… IMO `df["drama_movie"] = df['listed_in'].str.contains('Dramas', case=False, na=False)` is the correct pandas way to do it. You should ask your instructor for the reason. Maybe it's a wrong one ;)

Comment: not gonna mess with that women :D. I'm pretty sure there is something very valuable in the in-operator-way and I'm just to dumb to get it.

Comment: You should still be able to ask for an explanation.

Comment: you're right. will do.

Comment: Why do you need to use the `in` operator? You have a solution that works.

Comment: I will check with my instructor on monday in class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can split strings then explode lists then keep only rows that match your criteria:

```
drama_movies = (df.loc[df['listed_in'].str.split(',').explode()
                                      .loc[lambda x: x.isin(['Dramas'])].index])
```

Don't use `apply` here or use a comprehension:

```
drama_movies = df[['Dramas' in s.split(',') for s in df['listed_in']]]

# For 200 rows
# apply: 1.16 ms ± 20.1 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
# comprehension: 156 µs ± 262 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```